# Running SET command in Perl

Tags: windows, perl

I am using Perl version 5.22 ,And I am trying to SET an Environment variable though Perl script using the System function.
But the SET command is not working.
I am using the like this

```
my $return_val = system(" SET D:\Path\Folder ");
the return_val returns value 256.
```

Comment: The command you are trying to run has a syntax error. `set` requires a variable name to set and a value to set it to, separated by an equals sign.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you clean up the syntax errors, you still have the problem that you seem to misunderstand how environment variables and the `system` command work.

- Environment Variables are process level values that are passed on to any spawned child processes.  They do not pass from Child to Parent.
- The `system` command spawns a child process to do some work.

The problem you've got here is that even if you set the environment variable in the child shell, when that child shell dies & passes control back to perl, the environment variable has died with it.

- If you need an Environment variable that Perl can pass on to later child processes, look into using the `%ENV` hash.
- If you would like to affect the environment of perl's parent process then the best you can hope to do is build a shell script, batch file, or the like that can be processed by the parent itself.

Comment: Actually there are Windows-specific API functions to set environment and broadcast change message to system so other process spawned independently from perl would see those changes too. I did a small module on CPAN called Win32::Env that just a thin wrapper for those calls, but **it doesn't work right now**, though it can be fixed with some minimal effort when I have time. Until then people can check source and roll their own solution.